# Protecting the pruned stem of a yucca with wax?

Tags: houseplants, pruning

As mentioned in [another question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/59065/30447) I have a large yucca houseplant which I need to prune back. I live in central New York State (USA) which has a temperate & wettish climate.

I noticed in a couple of other sources that people use what seems to be melted wax to cover the pruned surface. But these examples haven't had any explanation for WHY this is done or what type of wax was used. There are a number of different types of candle wax and I wouldn't want to poison the plant by mistake.

[Example 1](https://youtu.be/hb7VMS64LXw?t=129) (really seems to be a normal candle?)

[Example 2](https://youtu.be/WIsYqmhKo_I?t=184) (hard "waxy" shell visible)

Still from example 2:

[image]

Is doing this a good idea, and if so, what's the right approach? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by growers who are propagating Mass Canes and Yuccas in hot tropical climates with high humidity and daily irrigation.  It can prevent mold or rot starting.

Homes and apartments are much drier and this does not need to be done.